# Javascript function dropdown making applicable to multiple dropdowns

Tags: javascript, html

I have two div's I'm trying to make into drop downs, one called accountAcc and another called forumAcc however whenever I click on accountAcc div or forumAcc it only displays accountAcc, how can I differentiate the two or accomplish this task?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
 function w3_open() {
document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "12%";
document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "12%";
document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("openNav").style.display = 'none';
}
function w3_close() {
document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0%";
document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("openNav").style.display = "inline-block";
}
function myAccFunc() {
  var x = document.getElementById("accountAcc", "forumAcc");
  if (x.className.indexOf("w3-show") == -1) {
    x.className += " w3-show";
    x.previousElementSibling.className += "w3-green";
} else {
    x.className = x.className.replace("w3-show", "");
    x.previousElementSibling.className =
    x.previousElementSibling.className.replace(" w3-green", "");
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: you can select only one element with `var x = document.getElementById`, so only `accountAcc` is being selected

Comment: What could I do in order to make it so I can apply it to multiple elements? Sorry fairly new to javascript

Comment: maybe you'd want to use same class on both of those elements, and then use getElementsByClassName